# How to reorder column values in a table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

When I delete some rows from a table it looks like the following table after removing:

```
+-----+--------+----------+
| ID  |  Name  | Address  |
+-----+--------+----------+
| 1   | name1  | address1 |
| 2   | name2  | address2 |
| 8   | name8  | address8 |
| 9   | name9  | address9 |
+-----+--------+----------+
```

The problem is the `ID` isn't ordered properly.
I need it to be reordered like this:

```
+----+---------+----------+
| ID |  Name   | Address  |
+----+---------+----------+
| 1   | name1  | address1 |
| 2   | name2  | address2 |
| 3   | name8  | address8 |
| 4   | name9  | address9 |
+-----+--------+----------+
```

Is there a command to reorder the column like shown?
I'm using sqlite

Comment: If ids are auto-incremented why you need to change them ? Thats the way mysql works.

Comment: Why do you need to re-number? Don't build applications depending on the id values like that.

Comment: I need to do this because my im putting this values to a list, and I delete rows by its id, so if the ids not ordered it could delete the item in the list..

Comment: Problem is in your aplication, not in a db.

Comment: Agree with zchpit.  Have your list store the `id` column, perhaps in a hidden field. You can then use this `id` to delete the right row.

Comment: I would recommend to find another solution. Imagine you have tens of thousand rows and you decide to delete first. You need to update EVERY SINGLE row in your DB and that takes time and you need to do it atomicly. I don't know your specific use case, but I recommend update your list so it contains row id.

Comment: Ok, thanks all its solved by editing code to store the id

Answer (score 0):

I think this type of query should do that:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET ID = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable ti WHERE ti.ID <= yourTable.ID)
```