# reorder column values pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I perform a `Select` operation on a `DataFrame` in PySpark it reduces to the following:

```
+-----+--------+-------+
| val |  Feat1 | Feat2 |
+-----+--------+-------+
| 1   | f1a    | f2a   |
| 2   | f1a    | f2b   |
| 8   | f1b    | f2f   |
| 9   | f1a    | f2d   |
| 4   | f1b    | f2c   |
| 6   | f1b    | f2a   |
| 1   | f1c    | f2c   |
| 3   | f1c    | f2g   |
| 9   | f1c    | f2e   |
+-----+--------+-------+
```

I require the `val` column to be ordered group wise based on another field `Feat1` like the following:

```
+-----+--------+-------+
| val |  Feat1 | Feat2 |
+-----+--------+-------+
| 1   | f1a    | f2a   |
| 2   | f1a    | f2b   |
| 3   | f1a    | f2d   |
| 1   | f1b    | f2c   |
| 2   | f1b    | f2a   |
| 3   | f1b    | f2f   |
| 1   | f1c    | f2c   |
| 2   | f1c    | f2g   |
| 3   | f1c    | f2e   |
+-----+--------+-------+
```

**NOTE** that the `val` values don't depend on the order of `Feat2` but are instead ordered based on their original `val` values.

Is there a command to reorder the column value in PySpark as required.

**NOTE**: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29624447/how-to-reorder-column-values-in-a-table) exists for the same but is specific to SQL-lite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = [(1, 'f1a', 'f2a'),
 (2, 'f1a', 'f2b'),
 (8, 'f1b', 'f2f'),
 (9, 'f1a', 'f2d'),
 (4, 'f1b', 'f2c'),
 (6, 'f1b', 'f2a'),
 (1, 'f1c', 'f2c'),
 (3, 'f1c', 'f2g'),
 (9, 'f1c', 'f2e')]              

table = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ['val', 'Feat1', 'Feat2'])
```

Edit: For this purpose, you can use window with rank function:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank

w = Window.partitionBy('Feat1').orderBy('val')

table.withColumn('val', rank().over(w)).orderBy('Feat1').show()
+---+-----+-----+
|val|Feat1|Feat2|
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|  f1a|  f2a|
|  2|  f1a|  f2b|
|  3|  f1a|  f2d|
|  1|  f1b|  f2c|
|  2|  f1b|  f2a|
|  3|  f1b|  f2f|
|  1|  f1c|  f2c|
|  2|  f1c|  f2g|
|  3|  f1c|  f2e|
+---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: the `orderBy` is not an issue, the main requirement as pointed out in the question is that I require the `val` values to be re initialized to 1, 2, 3 ... and not kept the same as they were initially.